# Bosch Nyon computer -- syncs but no activities are transferred

Tags: electric-bike, electronics

I have an electric bike with a Bosch engine (Performance Line) and a Nyon Computer.

My eBike Connect app (on iPhone) is able to connect to the Nyon (see screenshot)

[image]

but no activities are synchronised

[image]

although on the Nyon the activities are present

[image]

Is there a way to make the app see the activities on the Nyon?

Comment: When voting down it would be nice to comment.

Comment: While questions regarding eBikes are currently fine in this community, there is still probably something of a divide regarding whether or not they should qualify as a bicycle.

Comment: @ChrisinAK I get you point but they are bicycles. The engine just gives you an addition but you still have to pedal. And there is even a tag "electric-bike".

Comment: In my opinion they aren't.  Once you add anything besides human power to a bicycle, it is no longer a bicycle.  It's just an opinion, but not likely to change.

Comment: It's a valid opinion but every other component is from a bicycle, hence it make sense to ask here...

Comment: It's a fine line.  If someone takes a gas engine (there are kits) and mounts it to a downhill rig to make an offroad dirt bike, I certainly wouldn't want to see questions regarding engine compression and tuning the petrol portion.  Again, once you add an external power source, it is no longer a bicycle in my mind.

Comment: This is not the place for this conversation.  It is irrelevant whether you consider it a bicycle @ChrisinAK, since as you yourself stated, questions about eBikes are acceptable at the moment.  If you want to change that, take it to Meta.  Don't attack an individual OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting a (negative) comment on Facebook I finally got a contact email address: contact@bosch-ebike.com

They were very quick and confirmed the problems. They will release a fix soon.

> Es tut uns leid, aber wir habenmit den Aktivitäten ein wenig Probleme. Wir arbeiten mit Hochdruck daran, diese zu beheben.Wir bitten Sie deshalb hier, umein wenig Geduld.
>   Sorry

Not a solution yet, but at least I will stop trying to fix the problem.

Comment: That appears to be German, but I'm not certain. It would be most helpful if you would add a second quote block showing a translation to English.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove the Nyon from your bike, don't turn it off, as removing it from the bike is its signal to transfer data by bluetooth to your phone. It then turns itself off automatically after 5 mins.